# Response headers in express.js application

Tags: node.js, express

I am setting the response headers as follows in my express app:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
});
```

However when the server sends an response they arrive as below:

```
Response headers
0:A
1:c
10:t
11:r
12:o
13:l
14:-
15:A
16:l
17:l
18:o
19:w
2:c
20:-
21:M
22:e
23:t
24:h
25:o
26:d
27:s
3:e
4:s
5:s
6:-
7:C
8:o
9:n
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

Any clue how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from:

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE');
```

to

```
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE');
```